# How to set jsse.enableSNIExtension to false when running Java programs?

Tags: java

I am trying to set the Java system property `jsse.enableSNIExtension` to `false`, but when I try running this `java` just outputs help information:

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the name of the class to run. Normally Java programs are run like this:

```
$ java MainClass
$ java -jar foobar.jar
```

You can use `-D` to set system properties, but you still need the class or JAR to run:

```
$ java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false MainClass
$ java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false -jar foobar.jar
```

As far as I know you can't set system properties permanently; even if you did it programmatically it would only be for that run, so you need to keep passing the `-D` flag each time you run whatever it is that's not working

Comment: thanks for you answer. Is there possibility to change that variable on client side ?

Comment: @mibzer I don't know what you mean by "client side"

Comment: I mean by changing this variable not by connecting to server and change it but rather doing it over Java Console.